# How to connect Android device as Jenkins slave to execute automatic tests

Tags: android, jenkins, appium, robotframework, jenkins-agent

I am trying to execute automatic tests using robotframework + appium + Jenkins.
My biggest problem is to set up the necessary infrastructure.

I have a Windows VM (slave) with 4GB RAM but the emulator took more than 30 minutes to getting started.

I do not have a physical server to connect the device by USB.

How can I set this up in a efficiently way?

Is it possible to set up an Android device directly as slave (connected to master via wi-fi) and install robotframework in the device?

How many RAM/CPU I need If I need to get a better VM where I can handle the emulator efficiently?

I appreciate suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely you manage to configure your Android phone as a Jenkins slave. It's just too many libraries that you would need to build on your own so they run natively on Android. You would need to have the Jenkins slave, Appium, Robot Framework and your app running in the same phone, which isn't as powerful as any regular computer.

However, **if your device is rooted**, you can try something like [WiFi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb) to at least get the lowest level layer to your phone available over the air. There is also a manual setup with no software available at [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp/44460975).

If rooting is not your option, but you can connect the device through USB **just once** (which I assume you can't do because probably you're using a cloud host like Azure and that's why you can't physically access the machine), do it and run `adb tcip 5555` (or your desired port). This will allow you to desconnect the device and use it over WiFi with the trusted computer connected through USB (until you kill the ADB server!).

After any of both procedures, configure your project as usual and set the `udid`  capability to the IP of your phone in the network (try to configure a static IP address) and its port, for example `192.168.0.24:5555`. Before running the tests, you have to run `adb connect 192.168.0.24:5555` so `adb` is aware of the device and Appium can find it.

You still will have some trouble getting the VM and the phone in the same network, but for that issue there are plenty of options available like configuring a VPN.